# Number of bits set in a number

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bit

The following the magical formula which gives the number of bits set in a number (Hamming weight).

```
/*Code to Calculate count of set bits in a number*/
int c;
int v = 7;
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);                    // reuse input as temporary
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);     // temp
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24; // count
printf(" Number of Bits is %d",c);
/*-----------------------------------*/
```

from:
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Can anyone please explain me the rationale behind this?

Comment: Good lord, there's no reason to memorize this kind of arcana except to show off (and anyone worth their salt should know the source anyway).

Comment: and of course, if you give such an answer in an interview, the next question would be "Explain". So no point memorizing, and frankly I wouldn't like seeing that in an interview anyway.

Comment: Show us how you worked out your examples, step by step, one line at a time, and we'll help you find your error (in an addendum to the *question* please; **not** here in a comment).

Comment: Anyone else find the 64-bit tag somewhat ironic for this question?

Comment: I would recommend you write your own c routine to find the number of set bits. It can be done with some simple shifts and loops. If you can do that from scratch it's much better than memorizing something like the above, as others have alluded to.

Comment: @Adam27X I disagree. No I don't remember that stuff by heart (I read Warren's book on bittwiddling though and *can* derive the solution), but you don't have to. You only have to know where you can get the source. Compared to the looping code this is a whole lot more performant and anybody using bitsets hopefully does so for performance reasons.

Comment: @WhozCraig 64 bit tag is not ironic it is wrong. The formula works compute only for 32 bit integers (look at original homepage)

Comment: And if you understand it, it should be relatively trivial to extend to 64-bit quantities ;)

Comment: Seems patently obvious to me.  (But then I have patent 6,516,330 on a similar algorithm.)

Comment: The answer to this question has lots of useful references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: @EliAlgranti I know its wrong; thus the irony.

Comment: @HotLicks: And [here](http://www.google.com/patents?id=SRUPAAAAEBAJ&printsec=abstract) I thought you were joking...

Comment: @nneonneo - But everything I write here is true.  And I never joke.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's really quite clever code, and is obviously a lot more difficult to understand than a simple naive loop.

For the first line, let's just take a four-bit quantity, and call it `abcd`. The code basically does this:

```
abcd - ((abcd >> 1) & 0101) = abcd - (0abc & 0101) = abcd - 0a0c
```

So, in each group of two bits, it subtracts the value of the high bit. What does that net us?

```
11 - 1 -> 10 (two bits set)
10 - 1 -> 01 (one bit set)
01 - 0 -> 01 (one bit set)
00 - 0 -> 00 (zero bits set)
```

So, that first line sets each consecutive group of two bits to the number of bits contained in the original value -- it counts the bits set in groups of two. Call the resulting four-bit quantity `ABCD`.

The next line:

```
(ABCD & 0011) + ((ABCD>>2) & 0011) = 00CD + (AB & 0011) = 00CD + 00AB
```

So, it takes the groups of two bits and adds pairs together. Now, each four-bit group contains the number of bits set in the corresponding four bits of the input.

In the next line, `v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F` (which is parsed as `(v + (v >> 4)) & 0xf0f0f0f`) does the same, adding pairs of four-bit groups together so that each eight-bit group (byte) contains the bit-set count of the corresponding input byte. We now have a number like `0x0e0f0g0h`.

Note that multiplying a byte in any position by `0x01010101` will copy that byte up to the most-significant byte (as well as leaving some copies in lower bytes). For example, `0x00000g00 * 0x01010101 = 0x0g0g0g00`. So, by multiplying `0x0e0f0g0h`, we will leave `e+f+g+h` in the topmost byte; the `>>24` at the end extracts that byte and leaves you with the answer.

Comment: this is one of the most useful answers I ever found on SO

Answer (score -3):

One liner solution in python for counting number of one's in a given binary number

> > > > [i for i in str(bin(n)) if i=="1"].count("1")